# ios InApp purchase getting EXC_BAD_ACESS

Tags: ios, storekit

I am working in app purchase while buying product method getting error **EXC_BAD_ACESS**

```
-(void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];    //GETTING BAD ACEESS FOR THIS LINE
```

}

Comment: code block corrected

Comment: Do you have in your code addTransactionObserver for [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] ? If this is the case, see if you added also method to remove observer. If you forget to dealloc or remove, use removeTransactionObserver .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error message a released instance is being accessed. It could be the instance of SKProduct, I cannot tell the exact reason with the above couple of statements, but in general you should ensure that you follow below steps related to iAP's -

1) Create retained instance of SKProduct and SKProductsRequest

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProduct *productID;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
```

2) In viewDidLoad add statement

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

3) In dealloc method add statement

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

Note - It could happen that when you open the view you add self in the addTransactionObserver, while closing view doesn't remove TransactionObserve, and again when we come to view it could have a handle to previous instance which doesn't exist.